KeyError: 'detail' - robin_stocks login error
This code sends an SMS code to my phone. However, the code gives an error without even giving it input for the SMS code.
import robin_stocks.robinhood as r

r.authentication.login(
    username=username,
    password=password,
    expiresIn=86400,
    scope='internal',
    by_sms=True,
    store_session=True,
    mfa_code=None,
    pickle_name=''
)

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-694de4805c3e> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import robin_stocks.robinhood as r
      2 
----> 3 r.authentication.login(username=username, password=password, expiresIn=86400, scope='internal', 
      4                        by_sms=True, store_session=True, mfa_code=None, pickle_name='')

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/robin_stocks/robinhood/authentication.py in login(username, password, expiresIn, scope, by_sms, store_session, mfa_code, pickle_path, pickle_name)

KeyError: 'detail'

How can I send an SMS code using robinhood?

Is that the entire error message? Any part of the code you're leaving out?

My best guess is that under the hood (excuse the pun), something is going wrong with the line data = request_post(url, payload). When it tries to throw an error in the line raise Exception(data['detail']), it runs into trouble because data apparently doesn't have the 'detail'  key like it's supposed to.

I may assume the next:

Check the source code of robin_stocks.robinhood.authentication.login https://robin-stocks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/robin_stocks/robinhood/authentication.html
as you may see there

     if 'access_token' in data:
        token = '{0} {1}'.format(data['token_type'], data['access_token'])
        update_session('Authorization', token)
        set_login_state(True)
        data['detail'] = "logged in with brand new authentication code."
        if store_session:
            with open(pickle_path, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump({'token_type': data['token_type'],
                             'access_token': data['access_token'],
                             'refresh_token': data['refresh_token'],
                             'device_token': payload['device_token']}, f) else:
        raise Exception(data['detail'])

so, I think access_token is not in data and part raise Exception(data['detail']) is invoked, but your data does not contain detail field and KeyError: 'detail' is raised.
